# Does a projective variety have only finitely many associated Hilbert polynomials?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, ample-bundles

Let $X$ be a projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. If $L$ is an ample line bundle, then $h_L$ denotes the Hilbert polynomial.

> > Is it true that, if $L$ and $L'$ are ample line bundles which are equal in the Neron-Severi group, then $h_L = h_{L'}$?
> >
> > Does this imply, together with finite generation of Neron-Severi groups, that the set of polynomials $\{h_L \ | \ L $ ample line bundle on $X \}$ is finite?

Can anyone recommend a text (book or article) in which these things are explained (to some extent)?

Comment: As Sasha rightly points out, the answer to the second question is negative because you can take linear combinations of line bundles. My answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/257097/82179) contains a slightly modified statement you can deduce from finite generation of the Néron–Severi group.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Do I understand correctly that your answer says that, given a choice of generators, one obtains a "universal" polynomial $p$ (in the sense that any other Hilbert polynomial is a very specific type of specialization of this one)?

Comment: Yes, that is the conclusion. (It's universal in a weak sense, because it depends on some choices.) I also worked out one non-trivial example, to show that it's not so easy to get a complete parametrisation of all Hilbert polynomials obtained this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes for the first question, by Riemann--Roch.

No for the second --- even in the simplest case of a projective line, the polynomial $td + 1$ is the Hilbert polynomial (with respect to $L = O(d)$).

Comment: You don't really need Riemann-Roch, only that $\chi$ is constant in an algebraic family.

Comment: Should that be $td +1$? I thought the degree of the Hilbert polynomial always equals the dimension of the variety.

Comment: @abx: Of course.

Comment: @Paolo Avi: Right, I corrected this.